# How to *clip* saturation in Photoshop to a specific upper bound?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, saturation

I know how to increase saturation, but is there a way to *clip* it a particular value? E.g. if clipping to 80% any pixels with a color that has saturation <= 80% remain unchanged, whereas any pixels with saturation > 80% get their saturation adjusted to 80%.

Yes, I know this will produce a terrible result for most things, I need it for a demo.

Comment: You can use the calculations menuitem to calculate saturation of a pixel then use that as a mask fir a saruration layer.

Comment: Modern photoshop (I do not have one) should have special HSB filter which separates hue, saturation and brightness to R,G and B channels. The image, of course looks weird, but you can apply curves to the channel which contains saturation. Let it get curve which is 45 degrees tilted straight line from 0 to 80% of maximum and then horizontal. Use the HSB filter backwards to convert the channels back to R, G and B.

Comment: (continued) In practice I wouldn't try anything complex because free program Krita has in Filter > Adjust > Color Curves direct option to draw the same limiting curve for saturation like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHUGs.jpg

Answer (score 2):

### Method using HSB/HSL Filter

First make sure that you have access to the *Filter > Other > HSB/HSL* filter. If it isn't installed, you can find it in the [Optional Plug-ins](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/optional-file-format-plugins.html) on Adobe's homepage.

- Open your image in Photoshop.
- Apply *Filter > Other > HSB/HSL*. Set *Input Mode* to *RGB* and *Row Order* to *HSB*. Press *OK*.

  [image]

  Now you should have a strange-looking image with hue represented in the red channel, saturation in the green channel and brightness in the blue channel.
- Apply *Image > Adjustments > Curves*. Set *Show Amount of* to *Pigment/Ink %*. Select the *Green* channel (which now represents saturation). Select the lower left point on the curve and set both *Output* and *Input* to *20* (because 100% - 80% = 20%). Press *OK*.

  [image]

  Now you have adjusted saturation to be clipped to 80% when it's above 80%.
- Apply *Filter > Other > HSB/HSL*. Set *Input Mode* to *HSB* and *Row Order* to *RGB*. Press *OK*.

  [image]

  Now you should have an ordinary RGB image again with the wanted adjusted saturation.

If you want to do this non-destructively, you can simply turn the layer you are working on into a *Smart Object* before going through the method. The resulting *Smart Filters* should look like this:

[image]

Comment: I would still use this method to make amask for a saturation layer because its less destructive

Comment: @joojaa, OK but wouldn't you have to be violent towards the mask instead to make it mask everything below 80%? Or do you suggest to allow lowering the saturation also when it's below 80% for a more smooth transition?

Comment: Sure. But the mask can be easily remade. While the color transform is rather permanent. But even if remaking is just as hard the mask is more likely to be understood to represent something...

Comment: @joojaa, Ah you mean from a workflow perspective. I thought you were saying the result itself was poor quality. This method could also all be done with smart objects btw, but it would be two levels deep and perhaps not easily understandable.

Comment: @joojaa, I've added a tip about non-destructive editing. I forgot that *Curves* actually becomes a *Smart Filter* if you apply it via the menu instead of adding it as an *Adjustment Layer*. So it's just a one-level *Smart Object*.

Comment: That is indeed better